# Monomers and polymers

Tags: polymers, reference-request

At Wikipedia a [monomer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomer) is defined to be

> a molecule that may bind chemically to other molecules to form a
>   polymer.

A [polymer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymer) is defined to be

> a molecule composed of many monomers.

These definitions are obviously circular.

**Are there non-circular definitions of monomers and polymers?**

Comment: Circular definitions for a circular concept.  These seem pretty good. I might embellish the definition with "a molecule or collection of atoms (monomer) that may bind with other like molecules to make a new molecule (polymer) that is comprised of their sequence."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have a look at what IUPAC say; they would be a reliable source to get definitions of chemical terminology from:

[Monomer](http://goldbook.iupac.org/M04017.html):

> "A substance composed of monomer molecules."

[Monomer molecules](http://goldbook.iupac.org/M04019.html):

> "A molecule which can undergo polymerization thereby contributing
>   constitutional units to the essential structure of a macromolecule. "

[Polymer](http://goldbook.iupac.org/P04735.html):

> "A substance composed of macromolecules."

[Macromolecule](http://goldbook.iupac.org/M03667.html):

> "A molecule of high relative molecular mass, the structure of which
>   essentially comprises the multiple repetition of units derived,
>   actually or conceptually, from molecules of low relative molecular
>   mass. "

These definitions are consistent with the latest [IUPAC Compendium of Polymer Terminology and Nomenclature, IUPAC Recommendations 2008](http://www.iupac.org/nc/home/projects/project-db/project-details.html?tx_wfqbe_pi1%5Bproject_nr%5D=2002-048-1-400)

Note that, historically, the definition of a polymer has changed somewhat. Up until about 80 years ago, polymers were seen as molecules comprised of similar empirical formula - benzene, for example, was considered a polymer of acetylene. It was Staudinger's work in the 1920's (contributing to his Nobel Prize) that defined polymers as macromolecules.

Answer (score 1):

The term "monomer" only has meaning in the context of discussing polymerization.

A polymer is a molecular chain where the links of the chain are repeated identical or a least similar units.  Examples where the units are idential would be polypropylene, polyvinylchloride and polysiloxane.  Example where the units are similar but not necessarily identical would be DNA and proteins.

A monomer is a molecule that can react to form a single unit of a polymer.

For example, propylene is a monomer of poylpropylene and amino acids are monomers of a protein.